# How are eligibility traces with SARSA calculated?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, sarsa

I'm trying to implement eligibility traces (forward looking), whose pseudocode can be found in the following image

[image]

I'm uncertain what the `For all s, a` means (5th line from below). Where do they get that collection of `s, a` from?

If it's forward-looking, do loop forward from the current state to observe `s'`?

Do you adjust every single `e(s, a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that they've reused the variables s and a in two different scopes here, but yes, you adjust all e(s,a) values, e.g.,

```
for every state s in your state space
    for every action a in your action space
        update Q(s,a)
        update e(s,a)
```

Note what's happening here. e(s,a) is getting incremented by an exponentially decreasing amount. But right before you go into that loop, you increment the *single* e(s,a) corresponding to the state/action pair just visited. So that pair gets "reset" in a way -- it doesn't get the exponentially smaller update, and on the next iteration, it's update will continue to be larger than all the pairs you haven't recently visited. Every time you visit a state/action pair, you're increasing the weight it contributes to the update of Q for a few iterations.